# How to scrape a data table from a webpage after applying a filter?

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium

I'm trying to build a data scraping tool, however, the values of the table change after applying a necessary filter. I'm not sure how to apply the filter using selenium or other tools.

My plan was to load the base table and then figure out how to apply the filter and retrofit my code but I am still stuck even getting the base table off the webpage. The filter I'm am trying to apply is located on a dropdown tool bar labeled "Slates" on the site ' **https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl** '

I'm fairly confident this code is getting the correct table:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl-qb?site=fanduel'
driver.get(url)
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='proj-stats']")
```

However converting it into a pandas dataframe hasn't been going well.

```
results_table = []
for row in table:
    temp = []
    columns = row.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='proj-stats']/div[1]")
    for column in columns:
        temp.append(column.text)

    results_table.append(temp)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-bdda19bc35a3> in <module>
      1 results_table = []
----> 2 for row in table:
      3     temp = []
      4     columns = row.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='proj-stats']/div[1]")
      5     for column in columns:

TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

Comment: you should be using row.find_elements_by_xpath which should return a iterable list.  find_element will return only a single webElement / first element identified from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to fetch Players Name and Salary and load into pandas data frame try below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl-qb?site=fanduel'
driver.get(url)
table =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='proj-stats']")))

Player_Name = []
Player_Price=[]
for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='player']/a"):
    Player_Name.append(row.text)

for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='rgt-col']/div[@class='rgt-hdr'][contains(.,'Salary')]/following-sibling::div"):
    Player_Price.append(row.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Player Name":Player_Name,"Salary":Player_Price})
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
         Player Name Salary
0          Drew Brees  $7.2K
1      Deshaun Watson  $8.4K
2      Russell Wilson  $8.6K
3   Mitchell Trubisky  $6.5K
4          Josh Allen  $7.7K
5    Matthew Stafford  $7.9K
6     Jacoby Brissett  $7.3K
7       Matthew Moore  $6.5K
8        Daniel Jones  $7.0K
9        Carson Wentz  $7.4K
10      Aaron Rodgers  $8.1K
11       Kirk Cousins  $7.8K
12          Tom Brady  $7.9K
13     Jameis Winston  $7.5K
14         Jared Goff  $8.0K
15    Gardner Minshew  $6.9K
16     Ryan Tannehill  $7.1K
17        Andy Dalton  $6.9K
18      Mason Rudolph  $7.1K
19    Jimmy Garoppolo  $7.7K
20         Kyle Allen  $6.8K
21       Kyler Murray  $7.8K
22         Derek Carr  $7.3K
23        Case Keenum  $6.3K
24      Philip Rivers  $7.2K
25   Ryan Fitzpatrick  $7.0K
26         Joe Flacco  $6.5K
27        Matt Schaub  $6.6K
28        Sam Darnold  $7.3K
29     Baker Mayfield  $7.2K
```

Comment: Thank you for the well-described help. This code runs great, now I'll just have to work on applying the filter through selenium.

Answer (score 0):

It's all there within json format in the `<script>` tags. for example, you can iterate through the slate ids and match those up with the players and salary for those slates:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats/nfl-qb?site=fanduel'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find_all('script')[12].text
jsonStr_slate = script.split('slates:')[-1]
jsonStr_slate = jsonStr_slate.split('schedules:')
jsonStr_slate = jsonStr_slate[0].rsplit(',',1)[0]
slatesData = json.loads(jsonStr_slate)

script = soup.find_all('script')[13].text
jsonStr = script.split('data = ')[-1]
jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';',4)[0]

jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

for each in jsonData:
    name = each['player_name']
    for slate in each['import_data']:
        slate_id = slate['slate_id']
        salary = slate['salary']

        for k, v in slatesData.items():
            if v['importId'] == slate_id:
                print ('%-20s $%-8s %s' %(name, salary, k))
```

**Output:**

```
Russell Wilson       $8600     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Russell Wilson       $8600     2:00pm Main
Russell Wilson       $8600     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Russell Wilson       $9500     2:00pm SuperFlex
Russell Wilson       $8600     5:05pm 4pm Only
Lamar Jackson        $8000     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Lamar Jackson        $8000     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Lamar Jackson        $8800     2:00pm SuperFlex
Mitchell Trubisky    $6500     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Mitchell Trubisky    $6500     2:00pm Main
Mitchell Trubisky    $6500     2:00pm 1pm Only
Mitchell Trubisky    $6500     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Mitchell Trubisky    $6800     2:00pm SuperFlex
Deshaun Watson       $8400     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Dak Prescott         $7800     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Dak Prescott         $7800     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Josh Allen           $7700     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Josh Allen           $7700     2:00pm Main
Josh Allen           $7700     2:00pm 1pm Only
Josh Allen           $7700     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Josh Allen           $8400     2:00pm SuperFlex
Jameis Winston       $7500     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Jameis Winston       $7500     2:00pm Main
Jameis Winston       $7500     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Jameis Winston       $8200     2:00pm SuperFlex
Jameis Winston       $7500     5:05pm 4pm Only
Jimmy Garoppolo      $15500    8:20pm SF @ ARI
Jimmy Garoppolo      $7600     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Jacoby Brissett      $7300     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Jacoby Brissett      $7300     2:00pm Main
Jacoby Brissett      $7300     2:00pm 1pm Only
Jacoby Brissett      $7300     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Jacoby Brissett      $7900     2:00pm SuperFlex
Patrick Mahomes      $8500     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Patrick Mahomes      $8500     2:00pm Main
Patrick Mahomes      $8500     2:00pm 1pm Only
Patrick Mahomes      $8500     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Patrick Mahomes      $9400     2:00pm SuperFlex
Carson Wentz         $7400     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Carson Wentz         $7400     2:00pm Main
Carson Wentz         $7400     2:00pm 1pm Only
Carson Wentz         $7400     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Carson Wentz         $8000     2:00pm SuperFlex
Aaron Rodgers        $8100     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Aaron Rodgers        $8100     2:00pm Main
Aaron Rodgers        $8100     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Aaron Rodgers        $9000     2:00pm SuperFlex
Aaron Rodgers        $8100     5:05pm 4pm Only
Derek Carr           $7300     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Derek Carr           $7300     2:00pm Main
Derek Carr           $7300     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Derek Carr           $7900     2:00pm SuperFlex
Derek Carr           $7300     5:05pm 4pm Only
Tom Brady            $7900     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Tom Brady            $7900     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Tom Brady            $8700     2:00pm SuperFlex
Kirk Cousins         $7800     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Kirk Cousins         $7800     2:00pm Main
Kirk Cousins         $7800     2:00pm 1pm Only
Kirk Cousins         $7800     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Kirk Cousins         $8500     2:00pm SuperFlex
Daniel Jones         $7300     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Daniel Jones         $7300     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Kyle Allen           $6800     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Kyle Allen           $6800     2:00pm Main
Kyle Allen           $6800     2:00pm 1pm Only
Kyle Allen           $6800     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Kyle Allen           $7200     2:00pm SuperFlex
Gardner Minshew      $7200     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Philip Rivers        $7200     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Philip Rivers        $7200     2:00pm Main
Philip Rivers        $7200     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Philip Rivers        $7700     2:00pm SuperFlex
Philip Rivers        $7200     5:05pm 4pm Only
Mason Rudolph        $6800     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Mason Rudolph        $6800     2:00pm Main
Mason Rudolph        $6800     2:00pm 1pm Only
Mason Rudolph        $6800     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Mason Rudolph        $7200     2:00pm SuperFlex
Sam Darnold          $7300     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Sam Darnold          $7300     2:00pm Main
Sam Darnold          $7300     2:00pm 1pm Only
Sam Darnold          $7300     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Sam Darnold          $7800     2:00pm SuperFlex
Matthew Stafford     $7900     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Matthew Stafford     $7900     2:00pm Main
Matthew Stafford     $7900     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Matthew Stafford     $8700     2:00pm SuperFlex
Matthew Stafford     $7900     5:05pm 4pm Only
Kyler Murray         $15000    8:20pm SF @ ARI
Kyler Murray         $7200     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Brandon Allen        $6000     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Brandon Allen        $6000     2:00pm Main
Brandon Allen        $6000     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Brandon Allen        $6200     2:00pm SuperFlex
Brandon Allen        $6000     5:05pm 4pm Only
Ryan Tannehill       $7100     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Ryan Tannehill       $7100     2:00pm Main
Ryan Tannehill       $7100     2:00pm 1pm Only
Ryan Tannehill       $7100     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Ryan Tannehill       $7500     2:00pm SuperFlex
Baker Mayfield       $7200     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Baker Mayfield       $7200     2:00pm Main
Baker Mayfield       $7200     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Baker Mayfield       $7700     2:00pm SuperFlex
Baker Mayfield       $7200     5:05pm 4pm Only
Ryan Fitzpatrick     $7000     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Ryan Fitzpatrick     $7000     2:00pm Main
Ryan Fitzpatrick     $7000     2:00pm 1pm Only
Ryan Fitzpatrick     $7000     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Ryan Fitzpatrick     $7400     2:00pm SuperFlex
Case Keenum          $6300     8:20pm Thu-Mon
Case Keenum          $6300     2:00pm Main
Case Keenum          $6300     2:00pm 1pm Only
Case Keenum          $6300     2:00pm Sun-Mon
Case Keenum          $6600     2:00pm SuperFlex
```